# Parse Apache Log in Ansi C

Tags: c, apache, apache2

Does anyone have a snippit of code to parse apache2 logs with ANSI C?

Comment: Do you have to use ANSI-C? I think it would probably be easier using Perl...

Comment: The app I am using is written in C, I'd prefer to use C.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: Perl/Python/Ruby/Shell is always easier than writting 'real' commands in C. Although there is a reason the really HQ, and professional, commands are written in C ( or occasionally C++).  Especially when dealing with parsing, and other considerably intensive actions.  I know many will disagree, thankfully this is a comment :P, but a C program carries so much value it's practically self-evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, [MergeLog](http://mergelog.sourceforge.net/) does have a basic parser for apache access logs.